# Maven Jetty plugin : packaging type [jar] is unsupported

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a created a project with SpringBoot and project packaging type is `jar` and also i added the jetty dependency into the project and when i am trying to build the project with `mvn jetty:run` ,build is successful but i am getting a message like this

> [INFO] Skipping keycloak-springboot-demo : packaging type [jar] is
>   unsupported

and below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dasniko</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-springboot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>keycloak-springboot-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <keycloak.version>3.2.0.Final</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How to run the project in jetty server with jetty:run command ?

Comment: If you just want to run your application using maven you can instead use `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem for 9.4.19.v20190610.  I had to add:

```
<supportedPackagings>jar</supportedPackagings>
```

Comment: where to add????

Comment: In the <configuration>

Answer (score 1):

The `jetty-maven-plugin` will deploy webapps packaged as war (web archive) files.

Your project is specified as `<packaging>jar</packaging>` which means Jetty has no clue how to deploy it (what's the web manifest? descriptor? libs? resource base? where does it scan bytecode for servlet annotations and features? etc)

Your spring-boot usage seems to be based on standalone embedded-jetty usage within spring-boot itself.  Using `jetty-maven-plugin` in this kind of setup is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Jetty version to **9.3.27.v20190418**

This work for me

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.27.v20190418</version>
    <configuration>
      <httpConnector>
        <port>8080</port>
      </httpConnector>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>-1</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <reload>manual</reload>
      <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
      <webAppConfig>
        <resourceBase>src/test/webjar-debug/META-INF/resources</resourceBase>
        <resourceBase>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources</resourceBase>
      </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried with versions **9.4.X** but none works