# run-forked Does Not Start Jetty Server

Tags: maven, jetty

I added a `jetty-maven-plugin` to my build like this:

```java
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run-jetty</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/repository/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/site</contextPath>
                </webApp>

                <!-- run only -->
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>

                <!-- run-forked only -->
                <stopPort>9099</stopPort>
                <stopKey>stopPlease</stopKey>
                <stopWait>10</stopWait>
                <waitForChild>false</waitForChild>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run the surrounding Maven project, the Jetty server starts fine and I can browse the webapp at http://localhost:8080/site/

However when I replace the goal `run` with `run-forked` I get the following info in the console:

```
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.5.v20120716:run-forked (run-jetty) @ project ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: maven-p2
[INFO] Forked process started
```

However nothing gets startet at http://localhost:8080/site/. At least there is no webapp there. The OS reports a Java process on port 8080 (two actually) and something listening on 9099 (I guess the stop handler).

I can't seem to figure out how to get `run-forked` to work as `run` (just in another JVM). I checked [the manual](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-forked-goal) for configuration I'm missing, but couldn't find anything.

`mvn jetty:stop` works, too and does **not** print "Jetty not running!", so there is a Jetty somewhere. Just no webapp.

How do I get `run-forked` to start my webapp?

Comment: Jetty 8.x is EOL (End of Life), consider upgrading. - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Maven plug-in worked, so I guess it's a bug:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.25.v20191220</version>
    <configuration>
        <supportedPackagings>jar</supportedPackagings>
    </configuration>
    <!-- Rest of config same as above -->
</plugin>
```

(**Note**: I needed to add `supportedPackagings` additionally to the existing configuration else I got "[packaging type [jar] is unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081537/maven-jetty-plugin-packaging-type-jar-is-unsupported)".)